# Two's complement addition issue

Tags: computer-science, binary, computational-mathematics, floating-point

In a two's complement system, 16-bit binary numbers $0010010010010010$ and $1111110011111100$ can be represented in the decimal system as $9362$ and $-772$, correspondingly.

Now, from what I've read and seen in examples, in a two's complement system, subtracting $770$ from $9362$ will look like this:

$$\begin{align}&0010010010010010
\\+&1111110011111100
\\=&1110000010001110\end{align}$$

But this number is negative in a two's complement system and it does not represent $9362$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The addition is incorrect.

Comment: There should be a carry into each of the two leftmost digit positions that make the two leftmost result digits 0. You also seem to have thrown away the carry into the eight bit position (from the left).

Comment: @saulspatz I'm doing it as follows (from right to left):

$0+0=0, 1+0=1, 0+1=1, 1+1 = 0$ ($1$ carried forward), $1+1=0$ ($1$ carried forward), and so on... Can you please clarify what is wrong with my addition?

Comment: Curiously, the carries are missing exactly in the two columns where there is an 1 in each addend _and_ a carry coming in from the right. Are you sure your bitwise addition table has the right result for $1+1+1$? Try computing $3+3$ in binary (with four-bit words) and see if you get $6$ like you should.

Comment: Independently of all this, 1111110011111100 cannot possibly be the representation of $-771$ because it clearly represents an _even_ number: the least significant bit is 0. To negate a 2s-complement number you **invert all the bits and then add 1**. You've forgotten to add $1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's $-772$, correction made.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Now with your notes I came up with $0010000110001110$ as the result of this addition. Finally my confusion is cleared. Thank you.